# GitHub API for Line of code and Branch age

Tags: github, github-api

What is the API to obtain the following details from GitHub?

1. **Total Lines of Code** in the repository
2. **Code commits per day**, with commit frequency
3. **Name of all the branches** and number of branch in the repository
4. **All the branches age in days**